# while I test my app, I get the follow error in the Android-Studio-Consol:

Tags: android-studio

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.firstproject, PID: 6019
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.firstproject/com.example.firstproject.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class android.webkit.WebView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class android.webkit.WebView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at com.example.firstproject.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161) 
        at com.example.firstproject.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x2040003
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:299)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:385)
        at com.android.org.chromium.content.browser.ContentViewCore.setContainerView(ContentViewCore.java:684)
        at com.android.org.chromium.content.browser.ContentViewCore.initialize(ContentViewCore.java:608)
        at com.android.org.chromium.android_webview.AwContents.createAndInitializeContentViewCore(AwContents.java:631)
        at com.android.org.chromium.android_webview.AwContents.setNewAwContents(AwContents.java:780)
        at com.android.org.chromium.android_webview.AwContents.(AwContents.java:619)
        at com.android.org.chromium.android_webview.AwContents.(AwContents.java:556)
        at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.initForReal(WebViewChromium.java:311)
        at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.access$100(WebViewChromium.java:96)
        at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium$1.run(WebViewChromium.java:263)
        at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium$WebViewChromiumRunQueue.drainQueue(WebViewChromium.java:123)
        at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium$WebViewChromiumRunQueue$1.run(WebViewChromium.java:110)
        at com.android.org.chromium.base.ThreadUtils.runOnUiThread(ThreadUtils.java:144)
        at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium$WebViewChromiumRunQueue.addTask(WebViewChromium.java:107)
        at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.init(WebViewChromium.java:260)
        at android

---

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view) ;
    final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etext) ;
    webView.setWebViewClient (new WebViewClient() ); 
    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_go) ;
    button.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick (View v){
            webView.loadUrl(editText.getText().toString() ) ;
        }
    });

}

}
```

Comment: Post your AndroidManifest.xml file

Comment: Please be more specific about where you think the error might be occuring.  E.g, what part of the script is apparently working before you encounter this error?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide context to your question instead of just posting the complete stacktrace.

Comment: post your related xml and complete source code

Comment: When I run the operation succeeds, however, the problem in the emulator does not work well. I see a message (unfortunately, FirstProject is stopped) I don't know where the error is, please help me

Comment: about xml : <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.firstproject">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <applicationandroid:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

Answer (score 0):

**Here's XML code :**
[image]

**Here's Emulator :**
[image]

Comment: Edit your question. Don't submit an answer unless it's an answer!